# Deleting items from list in uwp

Tags: c#, sqlite, win-universal-app

I am trying to delete items from my list on click of delete button but clicking once the list only gets refreshed and clicking again deletes item from the list.
Here is my code:

```
private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var query = BreakfastList.SelectedItems;
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            conn.Delete(item);
        }
        if (Item1.IsSelected)
        {
            List<DbManager> people = (from p in conn.Table<DbManager>()
                                      select p).OrderByDescending(q => q.id).ToList();
            BreakfastList.ItemsSource = people;
        }
        else if (Item2.IsSelected)
        {
            List<DbManager> people = conn.Table<DbManager>().OrderByDescending(q => q.id).Where(q => q.Reading == "Breakfast").ToList();
            BreakfastList.ItemsSource = people;
        }
        else if (Item3.IsSelected)
        {
            List<DbManager> people = conn.Table<DbManager>().OrderByDescending(q => q.id).Where(q => q.Reading == "Lunch").ToList();
            BreakfastList.ItemsSource = people;
        }
        else if (Item4.IsSelected)
        {
            List<DbManager> people = conn.Table<DbManager>().OrderByDescending(q => q.id).Where(q => q.Reading == "Dinner").ToList();
            BreakfastList.ItemsSource = people;
        }
    }
```

Item1,2,3,4 are items in my combobox
My XAML for the list is:

```
  <ListView
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              Margin="0,0,0,0"
             Name="BreakfastList"
              Visibility="Visible"
                >

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:DbManager"  >

                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto" 
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            Height="Auto">

                                        <StackPanel Width="50" Height="Auto" Name="GluStack" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Glucose}" Margin="0,0,10,0" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False"  />
                            </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel Width="80" Height="Auto" Name="ReadStack" RelativePanel.RightOf="GluStack">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Reading}" Margin="0,0,10,0"  IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel Width="130" Name="Read1Stack"  Height="Auto" RelativePanel.RightOf="ReadStack">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Reading1}" Margin="0,0,10,0" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Width="Auto" Name="DateStack" RelativePanel.RightOf="Read1Stack"
                                        Height="Auto">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False"  />
                            </StackPanel>

                                </StackPanel>

                        </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure as this is not enough information, but based on your description the first time your method runs (first click), BreakfastList.SelectedItems is empty; therefore nothing gets deleted. Then you update the list by setting the ItemsSource on it. After setting the ItemsSource, BreakfastList.SelectedItems will be populated and that's why it works the second time.

If you set a breakpoint on:

```
var query = BreakfastList.SelectedItems;
```

Could you check if SelectedItems contains elements? Or in the next line if query has any?

Also, can you please give the xaml for BreakfastList? How is it initialized the first time?

(Sorry I'm writing this as an answer, but I don't have enough points to be able to write a comment on your question.)

Comment: The query has this value both times {System.__ComObject}